# Oracle SQL Developer doesn't put in schema names in trigger DDLs

Tags: sql, oracle

In our test environment, the schema is prepended to the trigger DDL as one might expect.  However, in our QA and PROD environments, the schema prefix doesn't show in the DDL.  We always connect as the "SCHEMA" user so it hasn't been a problem thus far.  Is it worth updating the QA and PROD DDL's to include the schema prefix?  If we don't ever connect to the DB as a user/schema other than "SCHEMA", do we really have anything to worry about?

TEST DDL:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "SCHEMA"."MDATA_BIR_TRG" 
                BEFORE INSERT ON "SCHEMA"."METADATA"
                FOR EACH ROW
                BEGIN
                  ---CODE HERE.
                END;
```

QA DDL:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "MDATA_BIR_TRG" 
                    BEFORE INSERT ON "METADATA"
                    FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                      ---CODE HERE.
                    END;
```

Comment: How are you creating the objects in each case, and how are you getting that output? Is this from `dbms_matadata.get_ddl`?

Comment: The code came from a DDL export I did of the Test and QA DBs.

Comment: Using the export wizard in SQL Developer (which can be used on all objects subject to privileges and on step 1 of 2), I see a check box to include or exclude the schema.

Comment: @Patrick I didn't know that was there. I originally did my exports under SQL Developer 1.5. I have since upgraded to 4. I'll look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the SCHEMA is optional and only needed if you want ensure that the handled object belongs to a defined schema or not. If you "don't care" and always use mean your current schema, you can omit it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with omeinusch that the schema name is not that important (as long as the current schema is the same as the schema where the object is intended to reside). There is no need to recompile the trigger and make it fully qualified.

A common approach to exporting an object's DDL is to use the SQL Developer's export wizard which does allow you to indicate whether the DDL of the object is schema qualified.

**Directions to obtain DDL from SQL Developer export wizard**

1. right click on the object in the connection navigator and select export
   [image]
2. choose characteristics of export (include schema by selecting check)
   [image]
3. make sure file path is entered.
4. click next.

Comment: The show schema option doesn't exist in 1.5 but it does in version 4.  Thanks Patrick.